# how to find taylor serie for 1/z with |z| > 0?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have the following

[image]

and I need to give the Laurent development for |z| > 0.

The Laurent development in this form :

[image]

**and to give few a(n) coefficients**

How can it be done? normally we use the geometric serie, but how can I have a radius of convergence > 0 using it?

Comment: Taylor series around which point?  There is no Taylor series around $z=0$.

Comment: sorry, it's Laurent not taylor. Got mixed between the 2. so z0 = 0

Comment: In the complex plane?

Comment: The Laurent series for $1/z$ is $1/z$.

Comment: in the complex plane yes.

Comment: @Dr.MV I just saw your comment! I also need the development in the form I added in the question.

Comment: His answer is already in that form :). There's only one nonzero $a_n$ coefficient!

Comment: @zahbaz thx for the answer! I've been tring to figure out how to come to this conclusion? I'm not able to calculate the an coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Laurent series centered about $z_0=0$, we wish to find all $a_n$ such that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n = \frac{1}{z}$$

We may do this by setting all $a_n = 0$ for $n \ne -1$. Then,

$$a_{-1} z^{-1} = \frac{1}{z}$$

This will hold if $a_{-1}$ is a complex number that makes the equation true. And it certainly is.

$$a_{-1} \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z}$$

$$a_{-1}  = 1$$

Thus the Laurent series for $1/z$ is just $1/z$ itself. There are no other terms.

Comment: thanks!! I was having so much trouble figuring it!!